# detecting WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error

Tags: selenium, appium, saucelabs

sometimes Selenium/Appium remote servers fail :(
In this cases the test receives a `WebDriverException`. Specifically I am receiving this from SauceLabs:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy. Proxy error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: '87ffea49770c', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.14.94-73.73.amzn1.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_232'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities {...}
Session ID: db1bcb92c9e245c1b83129b58cd726a3
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=(//*[contains(@cl...
```

I am using TestNG and thinking about writing an `ITestListener` to handle these simply by requesting a new session.
But I am not sure whether a `WebDriverException` represents all and only server-side failures.

Any suggestions?

TIA,
Adrian.

P.S. Here is the full stack trace:

```
Session ID: db1bcb92c9e245c1b83129b58cd726a3
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=(//*[contains(@class,'public-chat')]/descendant::chat-message)[last()]}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:61)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:428)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElementByXPath(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:151)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElementByXPath(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElementByXPath(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:57)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
```

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace and the relevant code?

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: edited and added full stack trace

Answer (score 0):

A lot of server-side errors **are** swallowed up by `WebDriverException`.  In this case, it looks like the Appium instance may have stopped responding to the Sauce Labs infrastructure itself, so without any idea why, Sauce Labs was forced to return a `WebDriverException`.

("Could not proxy" usually means the Appium instance directly connected to the device or emulator has died, locked up etc.)

I know this was a while ago so the assets aren't available anymore, but one way of figuring out whether the problem was Appium dying or not is to navigate to Sauce Labs' test detail page and check the command log to see if the command made it thorough to Appium itself.